# How do i split the string of url link

Tags: android

how do i split the string on url link

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linkHref, ".ashx?JobID=");;
                   String community = st.nextToken();

                    System.out.println(community );
```

url link below

http://example.com/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19358502&JobTitle=Factory%20Workers%20in%20Oldham%20-%20Immediate%20Start%20Now&rad=20&rad_units=miles&pp=25&sort=rv.dt.di&vw=b&re=134&setype=2&tjt=factory&where=oldham&pg=1&avsdm=2015-09-10T05%3a54%3a00-05%3a00

Comment: what is ur required oupput ?

Comment: 19358502    this value

Comment: can you code it sir as  i cannot sir the code is scrambled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "http://example.com/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19358502&JobTitle=Factory%20Workers%20in%20Oldham%20-%20Immediate%20Start%20Now&rad=20&rad_units=miles&pp=25&sort=rv.dt.di&vw=b&re=134&setype=2&tjt=factory&where=oldham&pg=1&avsdm=2015-09-10T05%3a54%3a00-05%3a00";

    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("JobID=") + 6);
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("&JobTitle"));
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: i can se it now nithinlal thanks sir let me se.

Comment: how do i add System output to se the output string ? on this code sir

Comment: System.out.println(s);