# Split a string in android

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have a string after scan QR code is "MAT:TO:My address email;SUB:My title;BODY:My content;;". How to split address email, your title and your content from string this? Thank you all everyone!

Comment: did you try splitting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515417/how-do-i-split-the-string-of-url-link/32515547#32515547

Comment: I tried but it don't work
String s = "MAT:TO:abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com;SUB:Example;BODY:This is a string;;";
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "MAT:TO;SUBBODY");
  while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  System.out.println(st.nextToken());
  }

Comment: can you say the exact out put you want ?

Comment: I want to output is:
- abc@gmail.com
- Example
- This is a string

Comment: Accept the correct answer it will help other to solve issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java version

```java
String s = "MAT:TO:My address email;SUB:My title;BODY:My content;;";
String[] arrayString = s.split(";");

String email = arrayString[0];
String title = arrayString[1];
String body = arrayString[2];

email= email.substring(email.indexOf("MAT:TO:") + 7, email.length());
title= title.substring(title.indexOf("SUB:") + 4, title.length());
body= body.substring(body.indexOf("BODY:") + 5, body.length());
```

Especially Android official is used kotlin version:

```
val s = "MAT:TO:My address email;SUB:My title;BODY:My content;;"
val arrayString = s.split(";").toTypedArray()

var email = arrayString[0]
var title = arrayString[1]
var body = arrayString[2]

email = email.substring(email.indexOf("MAT:TO:") + 7, email.length)
title = title.substring(title.indexOf("SUB:") + 4, title.length)
body = body.substring(body.indexOf("BODY:") + 5, body.length)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help with my project!

Comment: Please, what is work of +7 in the first line email = email.substring(email.indexOf("MAT:TO:") + 7, email.length)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **split()** method.

If you want to split by "**;**"

```
String[] arrayString = string.split(";");
```

In your case you would get

```
["MAT:TO:My address email", "SUB:My title", "BODY:My content"]
```

and then split by  "**:**" or the other way around, whichever better suits you.

```
String email = arrayString[0].split(":")[2];
String title = arrayString[1].split(":")[1];
String body = arrayString[2].split(":")[1];
```

This is a bad way to do it, not very safe.

Or you could use `string.substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? because I beginning with java. Thank you!

Comment: Added the revelant code.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much!

Comment: String string = "MAIL:TO:My email address, SUB:My title, BODY:My content";
    String[] parts = string.split(":");
    String mail = parts[0];
    String to = parts[1];
    String part3 = parts[2];
    String[] array = part3.split(",");
    String emailAddress = array[0];
    String subjectTitle = array[0];
    String part4 = parts[3];
    String[] array2 = part4.split(",");
    String subject = array[0];
    String bodyTitle = array[1];
    String body = parts[4];